# Multiple wildcard Angular ng-content projections rendering only last one

Tags: angular, ng-content

Parent Component (app.component.html):

```
<course-card (courseSelected)="onCourseSelected($event)" [course]="course">
   <div class="course-image">
       <img width="300" alt="Angular Logo" [src]="course.iconUrl">
       <h5>Total Lessons: 5</h5>
   </div>

   <div class="course-description">{{ course?.longDescription }}</div>
      Edit Description: <textarea></textarea>
</course-card>
```

Child Component (course-card.component.html):

```
<ng-content></ng-content>

<ng-content select=".course-image"></ng-content>
<ng-content select=".course-description"></ng-content>

<ng-content></ng-content>
```

When I run the example above, among the two wildcard `<ng-content></ng-content>` (first and last) in the child component, only last one is projected and not the first one. Why both or first one not get projected and only the last one?

Comment: I think that you only can have one ng-content by defect (without select) that reflex the content by defect